# using footer tag inside blockquote from accessibility point of view

Tags: accessibility, footer, blockquote

from an accessibility point of view: is it o.k to close a cite tag with a footer tag inside the blockquote like it is shown in this example https://www.thewebmaster.com/html/tags/examples/blockquote/blockquote-tag-footer-element/ or maybe 'figcaption' is more recommended? What way is the most suitable for accessibility and screen readers when creating blockquote?

I've been looking at many articles and found them contradict each other and not clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spec for [`blockquote`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) gives you some guidance.  It [specifically says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element:the-blockquote-element-4):

> Attribution for the quotation, if any, must be placed outside the blockquote element.

In your webmaster example, the attribution is *inside* the blockquote.

The [third example](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element:the-blockquote-element-5) in the `blockquote` spec uses `figcaption` (outside of the `blockquote`), which you had considered.  That feels like the best solution for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the footer solution isn't appropriate as it doesn't convey the footer semantic. You are exposing in the accessibility tree two sentences inside the blockquote, without separating semantically the quotation and the information on the caption.

I prefer the solution with figcaption.